# Selecting a software license for a blog posting in CodeProject.com

Tags: licensing

I am planning to post an article on codeproject.com where I will be sharing some code I feel worthy of the effort - so I went and read the posting guidelines. It appears that I will have to select a software license for my submission. I really do not care about my material and what people will do with the code that I will give. If they profit from it that is all fine with me and I am happy to have shared my ideas. My concern really is more about my own personal protection that if the code I give for some remotest of reasons inflict damage to them or to their system that I should not be liable for anything. Or something to that effect.

My material is about patterns for ASP.NET CRUD operations. I use this pattern every single project that I have. It is absolutely harmless, but you never know really how other people will use it. I just want to have some safety net.

What license is suitable for me in this situation?

Comment: From [BSD 2 clause](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause): "IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."

Comment: Many other licenses have such a statement - you just have to read them.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Just about all open source licenses come with a liability disclaimer that try to limit the liability of the copyright holder to the maximum extent possible.
In how far you can actually limit your liability depends on the local laws of where the software gets used.

As there is no real difference in the liability disclaimers, all open source licenses are a good fit in that respect. As you indicate you don't really care how your software gets used, the BSD ([2 clause](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause) or [3 clause](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)) and [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) licenses would meet that as well.